# How do I create sub groups within table using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, dynamic, row, grouping

I am creating a stock portfolio.  Each row is a stock and it's data including profit/loss.  each row has a groupid that the user can specify.  The idea is I want to:

1. physically group the rows based on the groupid
2. after step #1 I want to dynamically add a row below that group with the subtotal of the profit/losses for that group only.

So each group can contain many rows, and each group will have one subtotal row that adds up all the profit/losses for that group.  I just want to make sure that subtotal row is always right below the last row in that group.

I will need to be able to do this whenever someone adds a new row to my table (I allow them to dynamically add new rows through the UI).  that is, if someone adds a new row and gives it a groupid of 3, I need to at that moment stick that row with the other groupid 3 rows and include it in the subtotal calculation.

Comment: Have you attempted to do it yourself? You seem to be pretty clear on the requirements, why not post your failed attempt and describe where it went wrong? I say this respectfully, but your question looks a bit more like "please do my work for me" rather than "please help me out with this problem".

Comment: not sure what you're talking about.  i haven't tried it yet because i can't think of a good way to do it.  i'm looking for pointers/ideas, not necessarily code.  i've recently started using jquery and have found a wealth of easy ways to do things.  haven't figured out exactly the best way to accomplish this.

Comment: Fair enough, perhaps I just misinterpreted the tone of the question.

Answer (score 3):

Use `<tbody>` elements to group table rows.

```
<table>
<tbody id="GOOG">
  <tr>...</tr>
  <tr>...</tr>
  <tr>...</tr>
</tbody>
<tbody id="GOOG_subtotal">
  <tr>...</tr>
</tbody>
...
</table>
```

with:

```
function append(code, amount) {
  $("<td></td>").text(amoung).wrap("<tr></tr>").appendTo("#" + code);
  var subtotal = $("#" + code + "_subtotal td");
  subtotal.text(subtotal.text() + amount);
}
```